# Dimiss ViewController when application inactive

Tags: ios

How to dismiss a view controller when the user is minimize/inactive the application.

Situation
- when user pressed on button. the app will be minimize, when user active back the application, user need to sign in again the application.

Answer (score 0):

Use `NSNotificationCenter` to be alerted when the application will enter the background. Add the following in the view controller you want to handle this stuff in, such as the `init` or `viewDidLoad` methods:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(methodToHandleItHere) name:UIApplicationWillEnterBackgroundNotification object:nil];
```

Then handle it accordingly:

```
- (void)methodToHandleItHere {
   // handle it
}
```